# Is there an Android equivalent to the Apple Word Tagger Model?

Tags: android, machine-learning

On the iOS version of our app we are using the Apple [Word Tagger Model](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/creating_a_word_tagger_model) so that it can assist us with parsing some complex sentences and that way we can extract the parts that we actually want. It is working fairly well.

What is the Android equivalent of this? Basically I would feed it a large sample of sentences and a classification for every word in the sentence and once it learns those I can pass it some new sentences and it'll tell me the classification of each of the words.

Ideally after training it, everything should run on the phone, not the cloud.

Edit: I figured I should give an example of what I want since I already played with the Bert Classifier and it isn't what I need as far as I can tell.

This isn't exactly what I need to parse but a somewhat similar type of data. I would feed training data like this:

362, house number
main st, street name
345-954-5555, phone number
central av, street name
W., direction
E., direction
John Smith, person name
East, direction
10th st, street name
and so on.

Then I would pass to the classifier a string like "Joe Doe 999 S. 2nd st, Maimi, FL, 741-555-5555"

And the classifier will tell me "person name, person name, house number, direction, street name, city, state, phone number".

We are doing something similar with the Apple Word Tagger and while not perfect, it is working really well. Is there something like that for Android that doesn't run on the cloud?

Comment: there might be libraries similar to the python library `usaddress` if your data is for something somewhat consistent or common like the example of US addresses

Comment: Well the address example is just a similar example, our data is different but the idea is the similar. Also it needs to run on Android ideally without adding a python or javascript runtime.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, my point was just that there may be a java library for this already out there

Comment: This seems kinda close, although it mostly tags parts of speech: http://new.galalaly.me/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/.

This post also seems relevant as its asking about java NLP libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11116390